# How can i use forloops in fullcalendar event?

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar JS , in my events i would like to place my events data into the event field. My approach is by using php foreach and loop the data retrieved from DB and place into the event field. But i keep having this error saying ',' is expected on the '{' section.

```
    var allEvents = <?php echo json_encode($v_calendar_all_event_list); ?>;
    console.log(allEvents);

 events: [
        <?php foreach ($v_calendar_all_event_list as $single_data): ?>
          {
            title          : <?php echo $single_data['cal_title']?>,
            start          : <?php echo $single_data['cal_date']?>,
            backgroundColor: '#f56954', //red
            borderColor    : '#f56954', //red
            allDay         : true
          }
        <?php endforeach;?>
   ],
```

The console logged data is as below

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{cal_id: '16', cal_date: '2023-01-03', cal_event: 'New Event 1 After Edit', cal_holiday: 'YES', cal_status: 'ACTIVE', …}
1
: 
{cal_id: '17', cal_date: '2023-01-04', cal_event: 'New Event 1 After Edit', cal_holiday: 'YES', cal_status: 'ACTIVE', …}
2
: 
{cal_id: '18', cal_date: '2023-01-05', cal_event: 'New Event 3 After Edit', cal_holiday: 'YES', cal_status: 'ACTIVE', …}
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

Is there any better way to place php array data into this JS array field ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a comma between each event in the array, which you're not currently outputting.

Eg. when you have multiple events, your PHP loop would currently be outputting:

```
{
   ... event 1 info
}
{
   ... event 2 info
}
```

But actually, it should be outputting:

```
{
   ... event 1 info
},                    <---- comma need here, to separate the array elements
{
   ... event 2 info
}
```

Of course, then, you'll just need a little bit of extra logic so that you only output the comma-separator when you do actually have more than one event in the recordset, and don't output the comma on the last event.

Ultimately, this is the reason for the error message that you're receiving, I believe.